# Debug Macro Not working

Tags: arduino-ide, iot, platformio, debug

I wrote simple program to test debug macros, but it gives me compilation error

**Program:**

```
#include <Arduino.h>

#define DEBUG

#ifdef DEBUG
  #define DPRINT(...)    Serial.print(__VA_ARGS__)
  #define DPRINTLN(...)  Serial.println(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
  // define blank line
  #define DPRINT(...)
  #define DPRINTLN(...)
#endif


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  String str ="Hello MrNams";
  DPRINT("Here is my string %s",str);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

**Compilation Error:**

src/main.cpp: In function 'void setup()':
src/main.cpp:7:50: error: no matching function for call to 'HardwareSerial::print(const char [21], String&)'
#define DPRINT(...)    Serial.print(**VA_ARGS**)
^
src/main.cpp:19:3: note: in expansion of macro 'DPRINT'
DPRINT("Here is my string %s",str);
^~~~~~
In file included from C:/Users//.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/cores/esp32/Stream.h:26,
from C:/Users//.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/cores/esp32/Arduino.h:177,
from src/main.cpp:2:
C:/Users//.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/cores/esp32/Print.h:81:12: note: candidate: 'size_t Print::print(const __FlashStringHelper*)'
size_t print(const __FlashStringHelper *);
^~~~~
C:/Users//.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/cores/esp32/Print.h:81:12: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
C:/Users//.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/cores/esp32/Print.h:82:12: note: candidate: 'size_t Print::print(const String&)'
size_t print(const String &);

Comment: Serial.print doesn't support variable arguments

Comment: format the error log as code

Comment: This: `("Here is my string %s",str);` cannot be handed over to Serial.print() which is effectively what you are doing. The argument set appears to be more appropriate for the C++ function printf().